# Spreading an object into parameters?

Tags: javascript

Is there a good way to spread an object into parameters?

Say I have an object

```
const obj = {
  name: 'puppy',
  breed: 'poodle',
  weight: '7'
}
```

And a method such as this

```
const method = (name, breed, weight, height) => {
  // do something
}
```

I'd like to do something like this

```
method(...obj)
```

However, this obviously won't work because I can't spread an object like that. What can I do instead?

Comment: @ Andrew, you can use Destructuring, check the below snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring to accomplish that, for example passing an object as parameter:

```
const obj = {
  name: 'puppy',
  breed: 'poodle',
  weight: '7'
}

const method = ({ name, breed, weight, height }) => {
  // do something
}

method(obj)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty easy, all you have to do is deconstruct *one* parameter as an object in the function:

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'puppy',
  breed: 'poodle',
  weight: '7'
}

const method = ({ name, breed, weight, height }) => {
  // do something
}

method(obj)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, instead of spreading you can do a [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) of the object.

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'puppy',
  breed: 'poodle',
  weight: '7'
}
const method = ({name,breed, weight}) => {
  console.log(name, breed, weight)
}

method(obj)
```